# How to remove the WN00 from digital scale VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Nport device to get data from a digital scale to a Vb.Net app and but i'm facing a problem trimming characters from the output.

The output raw data = WN0015.15 kg (example)

I tried to use:

```
Label11.Text = Thetext.Trim({"W"c, "N"c, "0"c, "k"c, "g"c})
```

But sometimes prints the value + newline the raw data like:

```
15.15 kg
WN0015.15 kg
```

And when the value = to `0.00` or `0.50` print `.50` or `.00`

My code:

```
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.IO.Ports
        Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelegate(theText As String)
            Private Sub UpdateLabel(Thetext As String)
                If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                    Me.Invoke(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), Thetext)
                Else
                    Label11.Text = Thetext.Trim({"W"c, "N"c, "0"c, "k"c, "g"c})
                    netweight.Text = Label11.Text.Replace("kg", "").Trim()
                End If
        
            End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim returnStr As String
        returnStr = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                           UpdateLabel(returnStr)

                       End Sub)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can `Replace()` twice instead of trimming.

Comment: "But sometimes prints the value + newline the raw data like" Are you saying you're receiving two different values in one DataReceived() event? If so, should you only keep the one at the bottom?

Comment: @Jimi is it possible to add more than one value to Replace()? like Replace("WN00", "", "kg", "")?

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes, the first looks ok but the other one shows the raw data
Ex:
0.00
WN000.00 kg
like there a newline after the first value.

Comment: You can concatenate methods, as `dim newString = [SomeString].Replace("a", "b").Replace("c", "d")`

Comment: Note that, since you `BeginInvoke()`  in `DataReceived`, you don't need to `Invoke()` after (and you shouldn't, really) -- You should probably call `BeginInvoke()` in the delegate, so you can detach your receiver from the UI, if/when you need to. -- You also don't need to declare a `Delegate`, just call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something more like:

```
Private Sub UpdateLabel(Thetext As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), Thetext)
    Else
        Dim weight As String = Thetext.Trim.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last
        weight = weight.TrimStart("WN0".ToCharArray()).TrimEnd("kg".ToCharArray())
        netweight.Text = weight
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, you just made my day pal, big thanks, works perfectly...